# Generate multiple tables using ajax call

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF and jsAutotable to generate pdf for the table that is in the DOM.
First of all I want to create multiple tables that are present in the DOM using a button click.
Secondly I also want to create pdf file for multiple tables using an ajax call to the server using another button. I have tried to look around for some tutorial but have not found anything specific. 
Can anybody help please.

Comment: Have you tried using the `doc.autoTableHtmlToJson` function? In general your question is very broad and it would be easier to help you if you showed what you have tried or what errors you got.

Comment: I am able to create pdf for one table. I have no clue how to create multiple tables. I went through the documentation but could not understand.Yes I have used that function
here is code to create the table
var elem = document.getElementById('employee-table');
var data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to create multiple tables. Since I needed to create two tables in my pdf file, so I needed to call autoTableHTMLToJson function twice after getting the information from my html tables. After doing this you can define the options for each of the table also. Since there is very limited assistance available for js auto table so if anyone needs help in this regard just comment below, I might be able to help.

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('employee-table');
  var data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);

  var elem2 = document.getElementById('employee-table2');
  var data2 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem2);
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of how this could be made more clear in the docs? The `startY` and `margin` options is already explained there at least.

Comment: Can you point out in which section of the documentation I can give some input ?